# Iteratees Error/Exception Handling vs Reactive Streams/akka-stream

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, reactive-streams, akka-stream

Surprise surprise I'm having a few problems with Iteratees and Error handling.

The problem;

Read some bytes from an `InputStream` (from the network, must be InputStream), do some chunking/grouing on this InputStream (for work distribution), followed by a transformation to turn this into a `case class DataBlock(blockNum: Int, data: ByteString)` for sending to actors (Array[Bytes] converted to a CompactByteString).

**The flow;**

`InputStream.read -- bytes --> Group -- 1000 byte blocks --> Transform -- DataBlock --> Actors`

**The code;**

```
class IterateeTest {
  val actor: ActorRef = myDataBlockRxActor(...)
  val is = new IntputStream(fromBytes...)
  val source = Enumerator.fromStream(is)
  val chunker = Traversable.takeUpTo[Array[Byte]](1000)
  val transform:Iteratee[Array[Byte], Int] = Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte],Int](0) {
    (bNum, bytes) => DataBlock(bNum, CompactByteString(bytes)); bNum + 1
  }
  val fut = source &> chunker |>> transform
}

case class DataBlock(blockNum: Int, data: CompactByteString)
```

**The question;**

My current Iteratee code works well. However, I want to be able to **handle failures** on either side;

1. When the InputStream `read` method fails - I want to know how many
   bytes/block have been processed successfully and resume reading the
   stream from that point. When read in the Enumerator throws an error, the `fut` just returns the exception, there is no state, so I dont know which block I am up to unless I pass it to the rxing actor (which I dont want to do)
2. If the output side fails or can no longer receive DataBlock messages because the Actor's buffer is full hold reading from the input stream

How should I do this?

How could I/would I be better of trying this using reactive-streams/Akka-stream (experimental) or scalaz iteratees over Play's iteratees because I need defined error handling?

Comment: Is there a way to do #1 without using a shared `var`

Answer (score 2):

(1) can be implemented with an `Enumeratee`.

```
val (counter, getCount) = {
  var count = 0
  (Enumeratee.map { x => count += 1; x },
   () => count)
}
val fut = source &> counter &> chunker |>> transform
```

You can then use `getCount` inside a `recover` or such on `fut`.

You get (2) for free with Play Iteratees. No further reads will happen until the `Iteratee` is ready for more data, and if it fails no more reads will occur. The `InputStream` is automatically closed when the `Enumerator` is done, whether from failure or normal termination.

Comment: Thanks - but this code wont work. You can't += on a `val x: Int`... I didn't think it was safe to make `count` a `var`

Comment: Oops, I meant to write `var` there. Edited. `var` is safe here, only one thread will be in the body of the `Enumeratee` at a time.

Comment: Thanks! Are vars also safe to use from within futures... In theory I could do a `count += 1` outside the Enumeratee code which doesnt feel 'safe'

Comment: Doing `count += 1` outside the `Enumeratee` while it is running definitely would not be safe. I'm really only using the `var` here because it is the easiest way to implement this, but you'll have to be careful about how you use the `var`. There is little reason to use `var` inside a future, it would be better to include everything in the return value of the future.

Comment: FYI - `Enumerator.fromStream` includes a call to close if you look at the source

Comment: Is there another way to implement this without having a shared `var count`?

Comment: Good point about `fromStream`, I've edited that in. Also I modified the code to encapsulate `var count`.